# When try to execute a cgi script, get the error: "[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, ajax, cgi, localhost

When I try to execute a cgi script (via a localhost), I get the following error

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Any ideas why **??**

Completely lost...

.

---

*Additional Information:*

The localhost is generated by the following

`python -m http.server --cgi 8000`

The cgi script is called by an ajax 'get' request (simplified)

```
ajax({
   type: "GET", 
   url: "cgi-bin/myScript.cgi",
   onSuccess: function(html){
       //do stuff
   }
});
```

I have tested to check whether it's the contents of the cgi script causing this and I am convinced it's not the problem. For instance, if I try to execute an empty 'myScript.cgi' in the manner above, I still get the error.

Also, the cgi script (written in python) works fine when run through the command line.

Comment: `"user" => "bradley"` isn't valid Python.

Comment: oops, let me edit that...copy and paste issue

Answer (score 2):

So turns out it was a server config error....

I came across this tutorial,

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/dynamic.html

which references a localCGIServer.py script available here,

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/examples/www/localCGIServer.py

And the server script gets the job done

*

For Python 3 change this line

`cgiServer = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_addr, CGIExtHTTPRequestHandler)`

to

`cgiServer = http.server.HTTPServer(server_addr, CGIExtHTTPRequestHandler)`