# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application for loading css file in python cgi script

Tags: css, python-3.x, cgi, httpserver

I want run a python3.4 cgi script on ms windows os,
(I use python 3.4 and windows 7 in this case and python3 httpserver module)
script can't load css stylesheet file and this is my httpserver output:

```
C:\Users\aliv>E:\winService\serv.py
serving at port 8000
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2015 14:11:24] "GET /cgi-bin/winserv.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2015 14:11:24] command: C:\Python34\python.exe -u C:\Users
\aliv\cgi-bin\winserv.py ""
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2015 14:11:24] CGI script exited OK
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2015 14:11:25] "GET /cgi-bin/winserv.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2015 14:11:25] command: C:\Users\aliv\cgi-bin\winserv.css
""
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 3499)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 305, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 331, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 669, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 398, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 386, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 677, in do_GET
    f = self.send_head()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 972, in send_head
    return self.run_cgi()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 1180, in run_cgi
    env = env
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
----------------------------------------
```

http Code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Message Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./winserv.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div id="topDiv"></div>
    <div id="midDiv" class="midDiv">
    <div id="Regform" class="Regform">
        <form method="post" action="./winserv.py">
            <label><input type="text" name="serviceNameField"/></label>
            <input type="submit" id="RestartBtn" name="RestartBtn" value="Restart" />
        </form>
        <h3 style="border: black 1px solid;">
            {message}
        </h3>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

http Server is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

class Handler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]

PORT = 8000

httpd = HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

python cgi script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-type:text/html\n\n")

ff = open('./cgi-bin/winserv.html', mode='r', encoding='utf_8')
aa = ff.read()
print(aa.format(message='!'))
ff.close()
```

chrome log is:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/winserv.css".
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When try to execute a cgi script, get the error: "\[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508074/when-try-to-execute-a-cgi-script-get-the-error-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-val)

Comment: @thefourtheyet this is not my problem, but thanks.

Comment: i solved this error with change all files directory except .py files to a different  folder other than cgi-bin .

Answer (score 0):

solved this error with change all files directory except .py files to a different folder other than cgi-bin .
but is this a permanent and right solution?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8VLn.png)

Hi All..

i too had the same error while running the program in pycharm. i reinstalled the python with repair install and then went into File --> project --> project interpreter --> select the python file path as i have selected in the below attached image. then close pycharma and open and install required libraries as per your project requirement in to this path and then run.......